# How to Open .wav file in php using SAPI.Spvoice

Tags: php, com, text-to-speech, sapi

```
$write->Open("audio.wav",SSFMCreateForWrite,false);
```

I tried it like this. But this error has occured:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant SSFMCreateForWrite - assumed 'SSFMCreateForWrite' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\converter\script.php on line 30
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Parameter 1: Type mismatch. in C:\xampp\htdocs\converter\script.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\converter\script.php(30): com->Open('audio.wav', 'SSFMCreateForWr...', false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\converter\script.php on line 30

Comment: What is `SSFMCreateForWrite`? Is this meant to be a constant in PHP? Try to replace it with number `3` instead.

Comment: Error is solved Thank You!

Comment: But I want to convert text to speech  and save it in audio file. This error is solved but audio is not save  in .wav file. any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure you know the exact location of the audio file?  Beyond that, you'll need to show more code for us to help.